# Promise.resolve() inside click handler

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to make some decorators for some event handlers: a few simple functions that take a handler **A** as parameter and return a function **B** that do some stuff and then call ***`A(...arguments)`***.

There is a decorator in particular that I would like to build, it should fire the handler passed as parameter, after all the other handlers. But I noticed that the *handling of clicks* is different if the event is triggered programmatically rather then manually.

This is particularly evident in case of  `<a href="some/path">bla</a>` tag, with an async handler on the ***`click`*** event, that waits for the next thread to finish its execution (ie at some point has **`await Promise.resolve()`**).

for example given this code

```html
<a href="">click</a>
<script>
    const a = document.querySelector('a')
    a.addEventListener('click', fireLastDecorator(handler))
    a.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('doing stuff...'))

    setTimeout(click, 10000)

    function handler(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log('done')
    }

    function fireLastDecorator(f) {
        return async function() {
            await Promise.resolve()
            f.apply(this, arguments)
        }
    }

    function click() {
        a.click()
    }
</script>
```

during the 10 second timeout I can click anytime I want on the link: the page is not reloaded because the `e.preventDefault()` statement will prevent the link to be loaded even if there is an *`await Promise.resolve()`*.

But when setTimeout fires its `click` function (programmatically), the page starts to reload itself as soon as the program awaits for the *`await Promise.resolve()`*. The function continues its execution after the awaiting (you can see the 'done' string printed on the console if you have the persistent log active), but the page is reloaded anyway.

I wonder why this behaviour is different.

This is also noticeable on input type submit.

EDIT

With the debugger I noticed that the script follows a different path when the click is triggered manually instead of via js: when triggered manually, the handler doesn't await for the Promise to be resolved, so the second handler is triggered after the first (as if the Promise.resolve() where ignored). When triggered via js, the handler awaits for the promise, so the second handler added is triggered before the first.

Comment: Your first callback is wrong. You need to encapsulate it inside an arrow function, like you did for the console.log, or it will be called immediately without waiting for the event

Comment: @Addict it has to be called immediatly. As you can see ```fireLastDecorator``` returns a function and is that returned function the value that I want to append as click handler

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that in the `setTimeout` case you you are calling `preventDefault()` in an `async` callback that has an `await`-ed Promise in it. When you await the Promise, the event completes and thereafter it is no longer possible to intercept it with `preventDefault()`.

Comment: of course it completes the event handling during the await, but why this happens when clicked via ```.click()``` only and not when clicked phisically via mouse?